# cannot find mysql folder in /var/lib/mysql in rescue mode

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, vestacp

I have I have a server fault. So I have boot to rescue mode and logged in using ssh as root. I have mounted all the disk and in fact I can see files, users etc. (I was using Vestacp as Control Panel). However, I can't find mysql folder. The documentation says it should be in `/mnt-disk/var/lib/mysql` but my directory is empty.
I even tried searching for `my.cnf` but I can't find it.
Could anyone know what could have happened?

Comment: What is the result of `mount` command?

Comment: aahh... nice. So the server is in French and i don't know French. There was a mount error that I had not see.  But after playing around, i have found it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with mounting the disks.
use these commands to mount.

```
sudo mkdir /media/newhd
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newhd
```

source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mount-drive-from-command-line-ubuntu-linux/